# Show that the operator $(x_n)_n\mapsto (\frac{x_n}{n}) $ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

I want to show that the following operator is compact:

$$T:\mathbb \ell^p\rightarrow \mathbb \ell^p, \text{  }(x_n)_n\mapsto(\frac{x_n}{n})_n \text{   }  1\leq p<\infty$$

Its the first time that I am trying to show that an operator is compact.

I know the following three definitions of a compact operator:

Let $T:X\rightarrow Y$ be a bounded operator, then $T$ is compact if

1) The image of the unit ball is relatively compact or

2) The image of any bounded set in X is relatively compact or

3) Any bounded sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ has a subsequence such that $Kx_{n_k}$ converges.

But I feel like none of this definitions can help me to prove the compactness of the operator directly.

Is there something like a "general way" to show this? At least for Operators from $\mathbb \ell^p\rightarrow \ell^p$ ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The *general way* that I got used to (at least for relatively nice operators) is using the third formulation. In other words, take a bounded sequence and show there is in fact a convergent subsequence.

Comment: You can use the ideas in (or just the result of) [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494479/a-relative-compactness-criterion-in-ellp) to show $T(B(\ell_p))$ is totally bounded (and thus relatively compact). You might also find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175251/how-to-show-that-this-set-is-compact-in-ell2) helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hint: If an operator can be approximated by finite rank operators, then it is compact.
Try to show that $\|T-T_k\| \to 0$  for a suitable chosen sequence $\{ T_k\}$ of finite rank operators.

Try with
$$ T_k: (x_1, x_2, \ldots)\mapsto (x_1, \frac{x_2}{2}, \ldots, \frac{x_k}{k}, 0, 0, \ldots ). $$
It is obvious that $rk(T_k)=k$, i.e., it is finite rank operator. Since
$$ \| T-T_k\|^p=\sup\{ \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{x_n}{n}\right|^p;\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p\leq 1\}\leq $$
$$\leq \frac{1}{(k+1)^p}\sup\{ \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p;\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p\leq 1\} \leq \frac{1}{(k+1)^p}$$
we have
$$ \| T-T_k\|\leq\frac{1}{k+1} \to 0\quad (k\to \infty). $$

Comment: Should't it be a $C<\infty$ instead of 1 for the bound?

Comment: @Duke $\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p\leq 1$.

Comment: Excuse me but I mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|^p\leq 1$. I just want to know if there is a reason why you took 1.

Comment: @Duke The definition of the operator norm: $\| A\|=\sup\{ \| Ax\|; \| x\|\leq 1\}$.